# Bash or Python efficient substring matching and filtering

Tags: substring, filtering

I have a set of filenames in a directory,  some of which are likely to have identical substrings but not known in advance.  This is a sorting exercise.  I want to move the files with the maximum substring ordered letter match together in a subdirectory named with that number of letters and progress to the minimum match until no matches of 2 or more letters remain.   Ignore extensions.  Case insensitive.   Ignore special characters.

Example.

```
AfricanElephant.jpg
elephant.jpg
grant.png
ant.png
el_gordo.tif
snowbell.png
```

Starting from maximum length matches to minimum length matches will result in:

```
./8/AfricanElephant.jpg   and ./8/elephant.jpg
./3/grant.png  and ./3/ant.png
./2/snowbell.png  and ./2/el_gordo.tif
```

Completely lost on an efficient bash or python way to do what seems a complex sort.

I found some awk code which is almost there:

```
{
    count=0
    while ( match($0,/elephant/) ) {
        count++
        $0=substr($0,RSTART+1)
    }
    print count
}
```

where temp.txt contains a list of the files and is invoked as eg
awk -f test_match.awk temp.txt

Drawback is that a) this is hardwired to look for "elephant" as a string (I don't know how to make it take an input string (rather than file) and an input test string to count against, and
b) I really just want to call a bash function to do the sort as specified

If I had this I could wrap some bash script around this core awk to make it work.

Comment: If you had tagged this question with bash, awk, or even python (the 3 tools you mention in your question) I expect you'd have got some answers. You might want to close this one and ask a new question with those tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
function longest_common_substrings () {
shopt -s nocasematch
for file1 in * ; do for file in * ; do \
if [[ -f "$file1" ]]; then
   if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
      base1=$(basename "$file" | cut -d. -f1)
      base2=$(basename "$file1" | cut -d. -f1)

      if [[ "$file" == "$file1" ]]; then
         echo -n ""
       else
       echo -n "$file  $file1 " ; $HOME/Scripts/longest_common_substring.sh "$base1"  "$base2" | tr -d '\n' | wc -c | awk '{$1=$1;print}' ;
       fi
fi
fi
done ;
done  | sort -r  -k3 | awk '{ print $1, $3 }' > /tmp/filesort_substring.txt


while IFS= read -r line; do \
           file_to_move=$(echo "$line" |  awk '{ print $1 }') ; 
           directory_to_move_to=$(echo "$line" |  awk '{ print $2 }') ;
           if [[ -f "$file_to_move" ]]; then
           mkdir -p "$directory_to_move_to"
           \gmv -b "$file_to_move" "$directory_to_move_to"
           fi
           done < /tmp/filesort_substring.txt
shopt -u nocasematch
```

where $HOME/Scripts/longest_common_substring.sh is

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                     
shopt -s nocasematch
if ((${#1}>${#2})); then
   long=$1 short=$2
else
   long=$2 short=$1
fi

lshort=${#short}
score=0
for ((i=0;i<lshort-score;++i)); do
   for ((l=score+1;l<=lshort-i;++l)); do
      sub=${short:i:l}
      [[ $long != *$sub* ]] && break
      subfound=$sub score=$l
   done
done

if ((score)); then
   echo "$subfound"
fi

shopt -u nocasematch
```

Kudos to the original solution for computing the match in the script which I found elsewhere in this site